# Graphql Fragments throwing error after upgrading gatsby from v3 to v4

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I am upgrading my project from Gatsby V3 to V4, and after installing all the dependencies successfully, when I run my project build, it is failing and throwing an error: "There was an error in your GraphQL query: The fragment "kontentCta" does not exist." Here, "kontentCta" is a fragment that was created globally for reuse in my project. Before updating to V4, it was running successfully, but after the update, it is throwing this error.
I've gone through all the documentation provided by Gatsby for migration but there isn't any thing which is helpful for my error.

This is the query for kontentCta and I've been using it in other component's query as well.

```
export const fragmentCta = graphql`
   ` fragment kontentCta on kontent_item_content_item___cta {
        elements {
            cta_label {
                value
            }
            cta_location {
                ...kontentCtaLocation
            }
            cta_location_anchor_point {
                value
            }
            cta_window_action {
                value {
                    codename
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;`
```

Here is the query of component in which "kontentCta" is used.

```
`export const fragmentCtaBar = graphql`
    fragment CtaBar on kontent_item_component___cta_bar {
        elements {
            ctas {
                value {
                    ...kontentCta
                }
            }
            layout {
                value {
                    name
                }
            }
            content_panel__content_panel_font_color {
                value {
                    ... on kontent_item_list___brand_colors {
                        id
                        elements {
                            color_hex_value {
                                value
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            type_of_cta {
                value {
                    codename
                }
            }
            form_link {
                value
            }
            form_cta_label {
                value
            }
        }
    }
`;`
```

This is just one example and there are "n" number of fragments which are used through out my project.

```
`    "dependencies": {
            "@babylonjs/core": "^4.2.1",
            "@babylonjs/gui": "^4.2.1",
            "@babylonjs/loaders": "^4.2.1",
            "@kontent-ai/gatsby-components": "9.1.0",
            "@kontent-ai/gatsby-source": "9.1.0",
            "@types/react-modal": "^3.12.0",
            "algoliasearch": "^4.12.1",
            "axios": "^0.25.0",
            "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.1",
            "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
            "framer-motion": "^6.2.6",
            "gatsby-image": "^3.11.0",
            "gatsby-plugin-algolia": "^0.26.0",
            "gatsby-plugin-breakpoints": "^1.3.6",
            "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager": "^4.24.0",
            "gatsby-plugin-image": "^2.24.0",
            "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^5.24.0",
            "gatsby-plugin-readingtime": "^2.1.0",
            "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "^1.7.0",
            "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^4.24.0",
            "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^5.24.0",
            "gatsby-plugin-zeit-now": "^0.5.0",
            "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^5.24.0",
            "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^4.24.0",
            "html-react-parser": "^0.14.3",
            "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
            "lodash": "^4.17.15",
            "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
            "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.5.3",
            "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
            "postcss-url": "^10.1.3",
            "proxy-polyfill": "^0.3.2",
            "react": "^17.0.0",
            "react-autosuggest": "^10.1.0",
            "react-babylonjs": "^3.0.17",
            "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
            "react-dropdown": "^1.9.2",
            "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
            "react-hook-form": "^6.15.8",
            "react-instantsearch-dom": "^6.22.0",
            "react-jotform-embed": "^1.1.1",
            "react-modal": "^3.14.3",
            "react-player": "^2.9.0",
            "react-select": "^5.2.2",
            "react-toastify": "^8.2.0",
            "react-truncate": "^2.4.0",
            "sharp": "^0.30.1",
            "typescript-plugin-css-modules": "^3.4.0",
            "webpack": "^5.69.0"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "@babel/core": "^7.17.4",
            "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.19",
            "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.19",
            "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.19",
            "@storybook/react": "^6.4.19",
            "@svgr/webpack": "^6.2.1",
            "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
            "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
            "@types/jest": "^26.0.1",
            "@types/node": "^17.0.18",
            "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
            "@types/react-autosuggest": "^10.0.1",
            "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.8",
            "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.5",
            "@types/react-instantsearch-dom": "^6.12.2",
            "@types/react-truncate": "^2.3.3",
            "@types/typeform__embed": "^1.0.0",
            "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
            "babel-jest": "26.0.1",
            "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
            "babel-preset-gatsby": "^2.7.0",
            "chalk": "^5.0.0",
            "core-js": "^3.21.0",
            "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
            "css-loader": "^6.6.0",
            "cypress": "^9.5.0",
            "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
            "eslint": "^7.32.0",
            "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
            "gatsby": "^4.0.0",
            "gatsby-plugin-postcss": "^5.24.0",
            "gatsby-plugin-webpack-bundle-analyser-v2": "^1.1.27",
            "gh-pages": "^2.2.0",
            "husky": "^4.3.6",
            "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
            "inquirer": "^7.1.0",
            "jest": "^26.6.3",
            "jest-junit": "^12.2.0",
            "lint-staged": "^10.5.3",
            "npm-force-resolutions": "0.0.3",
            "postcss": "^8.4.6",
            "postcss-custom-properties": "^12.1.4",
            "postcss-easy-import": "^3.0.0",
            "postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
            "postcss-mixins": "^9.0.1",
            "postcss-nested": "^5.0.6",
            "postcss-preset-env": "^7.4.0",
            "prettier": "^2.3.1",
            "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
            "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
            "storybook-css-modules-preset": "^1.1.1",
            "ts-jest": "26.0.0",
            "yargs-parser": "^21.0.0"
        },
        "peerDependencies": {
            "gatsby": "^4.0.0"
        },
        "overrides": {
            "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": {
                "gatsby": "4.25.4"
            }
        },
        "engines": {
            "node": "<=16.18.1"
        },
        "keywords": [
            "gatsby"
        ];`
```

Above is my package.json file

I've searched Gatsby v4 documentation for any syntax change in Graphql query but there nothing's there which is helpful.